# Sync Salesforce data to my web app

Tags: apex, soql, php

Good day everyone. I am using `php` and `mysql` at the moment and I am trying to sync my salesforce data to my web application. The scenario is this: When I will create/update/delete data in salesforce, I also want that those data will be inserted/updated/deleted in my database `MySQL`.I also save salesforce ID in `MySQL` to check what particular record must be deleted or updated.

So far what I tried, is that I am trying to used `outbound Message` and I've created a `php listener` to get the data from outbound message but I guess it will not work during deletion. So I am trying to find another way. What is the best way to do it ? If you've seen some good article for this topic it is much appreciated.Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct, this is not possible out of the box, using outbound messages. You could use triggers on Salesforce to signal your PHP application of any updates/deletes. Or you could look into using the Salesforce Streaming API, which I think would be the best solution. EDIT; link to streaming API docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/

Comment: @Lex thank you. My question is that , how will I signal my php application in trigger ? I mean what is the possible thing to use ?

Comment: From a trigger you could call a method that does a callout to your application (basically just calling a url on you application with the relevant action and id included). You can not do a callout directly from a trigger though, you'd have to do it in a future annotated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a apex trigger on after create/update/delete DMl operation to call a http callout class to send a outbound message to php listener.
Here are some standard doc for reference -

Simple Http callout- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm

2. http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/16/restful-web-service-callout-using-post/

Comment: Note- You have to have a asynchronous callout for it to work.( Trigger have a limit for 120 sec for which it can hold resource.)
3. for asynchronous execution - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this one. I will get back here if I have question. +rep

Comment: What is the possible not good thing to happen if I don't use asynchronous callout ?

Comment: It will give you an error - Callout from triggers are currently not supported.
And remember you cant pass sobject in future method. You have to pass a list of ids. and get the record with SOQL.

Comment: @Hope if this ans solved your issue. the pls accept the ans and upvote. :)